# Check if resource exists before rendering full page component on Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How can I check if resource exists prior to rendering full page component with Livewire? This is pretty simple with the Laravel Controller.

My route:

```
Route::get('/profiles/{id}', \App\Http\Livewire\Profiles\Manage::class)->name('profiles.manage');
```

I was the Profiles\Manage class to check whether profile exists or not before rendering the full page component.

I am mounting the profile data using the mount function within the component and trying to check if the profile exists or not (and redirect accordingly). However, the redirect doesn't work.

```
public function mount($id)
{

    $this->profile = Profile::where(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'id' => $id])->first();
    if(!$this->profile) {
        return redirect()->to('/404');
    }

}
```

I've also tried doing this within the render() method where the component view is returned but that method requires a livewire component to be rendered.

Comment: Just pass the model directly through to the mount by using model route binding, instead of passing just the ID. Then you use `findOrFail()` instead, so that laravel handles the redirect if not found

Answer (score 0):

As Qirel said, I think that `$this->profile` does exist with empty value, so maybe you could try with findOrFail in your mount method:

```
$this->profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!$this->profile) {
        abort(404);
    }
```

Or you can use this:

```
abort_if(!$this->profile, 404);
```